# Problem finding the potential function of a conservative field

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

I'm trying to find the potential function of this coservative vector field $$F\left(x,y,z\right)=(2xyz^2\ ,x^2z^2+z\cos yz, 2x^2yz+y\cos yz\ ) $$ so I can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to compute de line integral where C is the line segment from $(0,0,0)$ to $(5,0,5)$

I got this one
$$f\left(x,y,z\right)=x^2yz^2 +\ \sin{\left(zy\right)+K}$$
but when I evaluate the starting and ending points I got
$$=5^2\bullet0\bullet5^2\mathrm{\ }+\ \sin{\left(0\right)+K-0^2\bullet0\bullet0^2\mathrm{\ } +\ \sin{\left(0\right)-K}}=0$$

Can anybody tell me what's going on here. I saw someboy getting $$f=x^2 y z^2+cos(yz)+k$$ so that confuses me. Did I make a mistake?

This is what I did
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \left(x,y,z\right)= x^2z^2+\frac{\partial C}{\partial y}\left(y,z\right)$$

$$x^2z^2+\frac{\partial C}{\partial y}\left(y,z\right)=x^2z^2+zcosyz$$
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial y}\left(y,z\right)=zcosyz$$
$$C\left(y,z\right)=\int{zcosyz\ dy=\sin{\left(zy\right)}+G\left(z\right)}$$
$$f\left(x,y,z\right)=x^2yz^2 +\ \sin{\left(zy\right)+G(z)}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\mathrm{\ }\left(x,y,z\right)=2x^2yz+\cos{\left(zy\right)}y+\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}\left(z\right)$$
$$2x^2yz+\cos{\left(zy\right)}y+\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}\left(z\right)=2x^2yz+ycosyz
\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}\left(z\right)=0$$
$$G=K$$
$$f\left(x,y,z\right)=x^2yz^2 +\ \sin{\left(zy\right)+K}$$
edit I fixed F(5,0,5)-F(0,0,0)

Comment: Is the answer supposed to be $0$?

Comment: You should have had $-K$ the second time. In any case you should have done $f(5, 0, 5) - f(0, 0, 0)$. Also see your potential function. As long as you are between any two points in plane $y = 0$ (or $z = 0$ for that matter), the line integral will be $0$. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your potential function is correct. Your evaluation looks odd, I was expecting to see $$f(5,0,5) - f(0,0,0)$$ which gives $$(0+0+K) - (0 + 0 + K) = 0$$

Comment: Oh yes I mixed it while typing it's f(5,0,5)−f(0,0,0), thanks a lot for the help. I thougth I was doing something wrong because I got a 0 despite not being a closed curve

Comment: Yes, that can happen if, for example, you are integrating an electric field to find the potential difference, but the two ends happen to be at the same voltage.